# How to fix Attempting to launch an unregistered ActivityResultLauncher Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I have integrated Google's InAppUpdate in to my app and I get a crash on some devices. I was not able to reproduce the crash.

This is the crash appeared on firebase

```
    Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Attempting to launch an unregistered ActivityResultLauncher with contract c.c@5d5894e and input androidx.activity.result.k@c156a6f. You must ensure the ActivityResultLauncher is registered before calling launch()
```

Here's my MainActivity and I am checking the update in the onCreate method. Also the activityResultLauncher is created as global varible. As I am aware the restering ActivityResultLauncher shouldnt be done inside the onCreate method. Anyone had this issue?

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var appUpdateManager: AppUpdateManager

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        val toolbar = findViewById<MaterialToolbar>(R.id.toolbar)
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar)

        appUpdateManager = AppUpdateManagerFactory.create(applicationContext)
        appUpdateManager.registerListener(installStateUpdatedListener)
        checkForAppUpdates()
    }

    private val activityResultLauncher =
        registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartIntentSenderForResult()) { result ->
            if (result.resultCode != RESULT_OK) {
                Toast.makeText(this, R.string.something_went_wrong, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }

    private val installStateUpdatedListener = InstallStateUpdatedListener { state ->
        if (state.installStatus() == InstallStatus.DOWNLOADED) {
            popupSnackbarForCompleteUpdate()
        }
    }

    private fun checkForAppUpdates() {
        val appUpdateInfoTask = appUpdateManager.appUpdateInfo
    appUpdateInfoTask.addOnSuccessListener { appUpdateInfo ->
            if (appUpdateInfo.updateAvailability() == UpdateAvailability.UPDATE_AVAILABLE && appUpdateInfo.isUpdateTypeAllowed(AppUpdateType.FLEXIBLE)) {
                appUpdateManager.startUpdateFlowForResult(
                    appUpdateInfo, activityResultLauncher,
                    AppUpdateOptions.newBuilder(AppUpdateType.FLEXIBLE).build()
                )
            }
        }
    }

    private fun popupSnackbarForCompleteUpdate() {
        Snackbar.make(findViewById(R.id.cordmain), R.string.update_downloaded, Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE)
            .setAction(R.string.restart) { appUpdateManager.completeUpdate() }
            .show()
    }
}
```

Comment: Where do you cancel your task if your activity is closed before your `addOnSuccessListener` returns? You'll also get this error if your activity is already destroyed by the time you call `launch`.

Comment: Damn. I haven't unregistered the listener. Is that the source of the above exception?